# make HttpCookie shorter

Tags: c#

Can we make the code below shorter.  Thanks

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserID", "JLovus");
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Comment: This begs the question: Why? What scenario do you have that makes this much code annoying (or is it a question asked out of curiosity alone)?

Comment: change `AddMinutes(30);` to `AddMinutes(29);` lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserID", "JLovus")
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't much code. I can imagine it getting annoying if you have to do it more than once, though. In that case, you could use a function to do it for you. For example:

```
public static class ResponseExtensions 
{
    public static void AddCookie(this HttpResponse response, string key, string value, 
        int minutesToLive = 30) 
    {
        var myCookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutesToLive);
        response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    }
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```
Response.AddCookie("UserID", "JLovus");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserID", "JLovus")
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
});
```

Comment: Still shorter than the OP's code! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in 1 less-readable line as follows:
`Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserID", "JLovus") {Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)});`

Just because you *can* do something in less lines of code doesn't mean you *should* do it that way. Your original code was concise and easily readable. What I (and several other people) posted is harder to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but what is the point?

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserID", "JLovus") 
    {Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place it inside a function:

```
public HttpCookie AddHttpCookie(String key, String value, int timeOut)
{
    HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
    httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeOut);
    Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
    return httpCookie;
}
```

And call it this way:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = AddHttpCookie("UserID", "JLovus", 30);
```

Or just:

```
AddHttpCookie("UserID", "JLovus", 30);
```

Comment: I'll appreciate an explanation for the down vote here ...

Comment: I don't understand it either. I think this is a valid answer. Not as reusable as extension methods though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this code a lot, you should consider putting it into a function:

```
protected void CreateUserIDCookie(string userID, int timeUntilExpires)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserID", userID);
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeUntilExpires);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Then in your code just do this:

```
this.CreateUserIDCookie("JLovus", 30);
```

As others have suggested, you can reduce it to a single line, but as they've also said, it's less readable, and I'd rather have three lines of readable code, than a single line that is harder to read. Code is already hard enough to read.

Comment: Why are you passing parameters and not using them?

Comment: Because I copypasta'd the code from the question and forgot to change the literals to parameter names. D'oh!